# Consecutive business days in Javascript (no weekends)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do a 3 consecutive business day check against an array of dates in javascript. I have it working with any 3 days but I can't figure out for the life of me how I can make this work with the weekend breaking up the consecutive days.

**NOTE** - This requires **moment()** library (https://momentjs.com)

My code that works for 3 actual consecutive days:

```
var allDates = ["2017-03-07", "2017-03-09", "2017-03-10", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-15"];
var diff = 86400000;
var consecutive = 0;

allDates.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});

for (i = 2; i < allDates.length; i++) {
  var d = moment(allDates[i], "YYYY-MM-DD").format('x');
  var d1 = moment(allDates[i-1], "YYYY-MM-DD").format('x');
  var d2 = moment(allDates[i-2], "YYYY-MM-DD").format('x');

  if (d1 - d2 == diff && d - d2 == diff * 2) {
    consecutive = 1;               
    break;
  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see by the calendar above, I would like March 9th, 10th and 13th to act as 3 consecutive business days. Anyone have any feedback that can guide me onto a right path?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify - your array has 5 dates. Do you want to return true if *any* three dates in the array are consecutive business days?

Comment: Yes 3 consecutive business days.

Comment: What about public holidays?

Comment: No need to worry about holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working from all my tests so far...unless someone can point out an issue or bug.

**NOTE** - This requires **moment()** library (https://momentjs.com)

```js
var allDates = ["2017-03-07", "2017-03-09", "2017-03-10", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-15"];
var consecutive = 0;

allDates.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});

for (i = 2; i < allDates.length; i++) {
  var d = moment(allDates[i], "YYYY-MM-DD");
  var d1 = moment(allDates[i-1], "YYYY-MM-DD");
  var d2 = moment(allDates[i-2], "YYYY-MM-DD");
     
  if (d1.diff(d2,"days") == 1 && d.diff(d2,"days") == 2 ||
      d2.weekday() == 5 && d1.weekday() == 1 && d1.diff(d2,"days") == 3 && d.diff(d1,"days") == 1 || 
      d1.weekday() == 5 && d.weekday() == 1 && d.diff(d1,"days") == 3 && d1.diff(d2,"days") == 1) {

    consecutive = 1;               
    break;
  }
}
        
console.log('dates are consecutive: ' + consecutive)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript Date object to figure out which days are weekends.
Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

And a quick example:

```
    var d1 = new Date("2017-03-07");
    var d2 = new Date("2017-03-08");
    d.getDay() // this will return 1, which corresponds with Monday. 2  is Tuesday, 3 is Wednesday, etc.
```

So a small function to tell if 2 dates are consecutive, even if separated by a weekend, could be:

```
     var millisecondsInDay = 86400000;

     function datesAreConsecutiveBusinessDays(date1, date2){
       // If date1 is a Friday and date2 is a Monday
       if (date1.getDay() === 5 && date2.getDay() === 1){
         // And the dates are 2 days apart
         date2.valeOf() - date1.valueOf() === millisecondsInDay * 2
         return true;
       } else if (date2.valeOf() - date1.valueOf() === millisecondsInDay){
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
     }
```

So with this method, you go through your list of dates and call it on every two that are next to eachother.

```
     var consecutive = 0;
     var allDates = ["2017-03-07", "2017-03-09", "2017-03-10", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-15"];

     for (var i = 0; i < allDates.length - 1; i++){
       if (datesAreConsecutiveBusinessDays(new Date(allDates[i]), new Date(allDates[i+1])){
         consecutive++;
       }
       // If you want to start over if you hit a nonconsecutive date, add this else:
       else {
         consecutive = 0; // this will start the counter over
       }
     }
```

You might need to tweak the solution a bit depending on how consecutive is calculated, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your response but how does this come into play when the weekend date is not in the array of dates?

Comment: You could modify the `dateStringIsWeekend()` function to check if the date given is a Friday, and if so then you know that if the date after that is a Monday, they are consecutive business days. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, it would really help me out if you could incorporate some of my code with yours as well... if possible.

Comment: Sure, the second block is taking the list you started with, and basically the logic of your if block is getting moved to the `datesAreConsecutiveBusinessDays()` function. I'm using your millisecond date comparison because that was very clever, and now just expanding it to cover weekends as well.

Comment: This is good but should be 3 consecutive dates... I think yours only works for 2 consec dates

Comment: It should work for three, but answer me this, if the first two dates are consecutive, but the third one is not, what would you like to happen? Should the loop quit, or should `consecutive` be reset to 0? Or something else entirely.

Comment: 3 consecutive dates. not 2.  if not 3 consecutive dates, result should output false

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by writing a function which determines if any 2 momentjs instances are either 1 day different, or if one is friday and the other is monday (but must only be 3 days apart). Simply, this does it:

```
function isConsecutive(a,b){
    return b.diff(a,"days") == 1
        || (a.weekday() == 5 && b.weekday() == 1 && b.diff(a,"days") == 3);
}
```

You can then take your array of dates, turn them all to momentJS instances, order them and iterate through calling the above method for each pair. Keep a running total of the count:

```
function countConsecutiveDays(arr){
   var momentDates = arr.map(function(d){
       return  moment(d, "YYYY-MM-DD") ;
   }).sort(function(a,b){return a.diff(b);})
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=1;i<momentDates.length;i++){
        if(isConsecutive(momentDates[i-1],momentDates[i]))
            count++;
    }
    return count+1;
}
```

A working example is below

```js
function countConsecutiveDays(arr){
   var momentDates = arr.map(function(d){
       return  moment(d, "YYYY-MM-DD") ;
   }).sort(function(a,b){return a.diff(b);})
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=1;i<momentDates.length;i++){
        if(isConsecutive(momentDates[i-1],momentDates[i]))
            count++;
    }
    return count+1;
}

function isConsecutive(a,b){
    return b.diff(a,"days") == 1
        || (a.weekday() == 5 && b.weekday() == 1 && b.diff(a,"days") == 3);
}


console.log(countConsecutiveDays( ["2017-03-07", "2017-03-09", "2017-03-10", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-15"]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found an issue with this... if the dates are ["2017-03-14", "2017-03-15", "2017-03-29", "2017-03-30"]  only 2 are consecutive but its resulting 3 consecutive days...

Comment: @rubberchicken yep, it has 2 sets of 2 consecutive dates, my algorithm has a bug. Can you fix it or would you like me to update?

Comment: You can fix your version, i'm also going to add in my own answer which is similar to my original post